# Encrypt or Decrypt config sections in web.config

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, encryption

What is the simplest and best way to Encrypt or Decrypt the configuration section in web.config file for VS 2010. Is there any difference between approaches used in vs2005 and vs2010 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach has not changed in a long time - use the [`aspnet_regiis.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx) command line tool with the encryption parameters.